# Brunch / Phoenix error copying Thumbs.db

Tags: windows, phoenix-framework, brunch

Using Phoenix on Windows 8, when I go to run `mix phoenix.server`, it starts Brunch but gives the error

```
Copying of web\static\assets\images\Thumbs.db failed. Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, 
open C:\Users\myname\phoenix\appname\priv\static\images\Thumbs.db`.
```

Then it does a never-ending `info: compiling` loop, and I get various errors with my javascript.

As I was writing this I tried it again without changing anything, and now I get the error

```
(File.CopyError) could not copy recursively from "C:/.../test/priv" to 
"C:/.../test/_build/dev/lib/test/priv". C:/.../Thumbs.db: permission denied
```

This sprang up all of a sudden--not sure what I did that could have caused it. Does anyone have any ideas, such as perhaps somehow giving correct permissions, or ignoring Thumbs.db in brunch, or something else? Thanks

Edit: Well I think I correctly got Thumbs.db ignored in brunch with conventions.ignored, since I am able to do a standalone `brunch build` and it compiles, but I still get the above `(File.CopyError)`. Looking into eradicating all Thumbs.db files, but surely there's a better solution.

Editedit: I deleted all Thumbs.db (or at least tried to with the Disk Cleanup / 'Delete thumbnails'), also disabled thumbnails, but I still get the second error. Perhaps time to get a new os?

Answer (score 0):

Well, starting over with a new phoenix project (with old code pasted in) fixed it. Any thoughts as to what caused it or other ways to solve it are still welcome.